# Find a value for the equation $x=(1+1/x)^{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have to find a value that satisfies the equation $x=(1+1/x)^{x}$ where x is a real number, using calculation tools or real analysis. I have verified that the solution is greater than 2.2, but I don't know how to reach the approximate value.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, the numerical solution is $x \approx 2.29316628741186$. But there's really no reason to expect to be able to find an exact closed form solution.

Comment: Additionally, the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=2.29316628741186+&lookup_type=simple) cannot find a closed form solution so it is unlikely there is a simple one.

Comment: If you simplify you get $\frac{(x+1)^x}{x^x}=x$ so $x^{x+1}=(x+1)^x$. That turns into $x^y=y^x$, but from there it's really messy.

Comment: We can prove that $x$ must be irrational, as $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{\frac{p}{q}+1}=\left(\frac{p}{q}+1\right)^{\frac{p}{q}}\Rightarrow \sum_{i=0}^{p}\binom{p}{i}\cdot p^{p-i}q^{i}=1$ by the binomial theorem. But then $p=1$, so $q^{q+1}+q-1=0$, which has no integer solutions.

Comment: * "But then $p=0$"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could obtain *approximations* of the solution if, by inspection or graphing, you notice that the solution is close to $x=2$.

Writing$$y=x-\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$ expand as a Taylor series around $x=2$. This should give
$$y=-\frac{1}{4}+(x-2) \left(\frac{7}{4}-\frac{9}{4} \log
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{16} (x-2)^2 \left(-1-18 \log
   ^2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+12 \log
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)+O\left((x-2)^3\right)$$ Using the expansion to $O\left((x-2)^2\right)$, this would give
$$x=2+\frac{1}{7-9 \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)} \approx 2.298435$$
Using the expansion to $O\left((x-2)^3\right)$, this is a quadratic in $(x-2)$; the solution is quite massy but numerically this gives $x \approx 2.2926446$.

Another possible solution could be to use more terms in the series expansion of $y$ and use later series reversion, for example, using the expansion to $O\left((x-2)^5\right)$, you should obtain $x=2.292644$.

However, it would be so simple to use Newton method; starting with $x_0=2$, the iterates would be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.000000000 \\
 1 & 2.298434945 \\
 2 & 2.293167635 \\
 3 & 2.293166287
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Without numerical method, we could even do it better building around $x=2$ the $[1,n]$ Padé approximant. They will write
$$P_n=\frac{-\frac 14 + a_{(n)}(x-2)} {1+\sum_{k=1}^n b_{k,(n)}(x-2)^k }$$ This would be equivalent to the first iteration of Newton $(n=0)$, Halley $(n=1)$, Householder $(n=2)$, $\cdots$ methods. Then, solving  for $0$, the solution will be
$$x_{(n)}=2+\frac 1 {4a_{(n)}}$$ The formulae would be quite messy but totally explicit. Computing them, we should get the following values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_{(n)} \\
 0 &  2.29843494504 \\
 1 &  2.29253149259 \\
 2 &  2.29324350331 \\
 3 &  2.29315683058 \\
 4 &  2.29316745391 \\
 5 &  2.29316614251 \\
 6 &  2.29316630554
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Newton is the best here, as usual.